Crypto/blockchain: I have tokens for which I want to find the price using dex like raydium
My goal is to get a token price from the dex sdk available/api in the market.
I have used Jupiter price api priorly, however I want to the price to be current and not outdated. Kindly guide or point in the right direction.
I have looked through sites like gecko, where they give out the price pool for different dexes. However, I am not sure on how to convert them to token prices.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
